# How to parse default query parameter in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to read the values of URL query parameters using AngularJS. I'm accessing the HTML with the following URL:

http://demo.com/demo/demo.html?param1=125&param=4

The controller:

```js
App.controller( 'DrawsController', ['$scope','$q','$location','$http', function($scope,$q,$location,$http){
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 $http({
  url: "./api/api.php",
  method: "get",
  dataType: "json",
  params: {
   param1: $location.param1,
   param: $location.param
  }
 })
 .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

 })
 .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

 });
 deferred.promise;
}]);
```

Comment: @neelsg i want to get parameter from give url using angular for third party api request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var searchObject = $location.search();
var param1 = searchObject.param1;
var param = searchObject.param;
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more context or explanation to your answer